# How to add a package to the package list in ROS.org wiki

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I would like to add my package on GitHub to the package list in ROS.org wiki.
-> http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php

Is there a manual about it?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234332/how-to-add-a-package-to-the-package-list-in-ros.org-wiki./) by [Atsushi Sakai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26860/atsushi-sakai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What they call `release` is the way to go. In ROS it's conveniently done by using a tool called `bloom`. [Here is a set of tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials) for making a release using bloom. In particular, see [FirstTimeRelease](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/FirstTimeRelease) in the first place.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1